# Knit unable to install packages

Tags: r, knitr

I have created a .Rmd file with some R code which runs fine. Then, when I try to click the Knit button in RStudio to convert into HTML, it gives errors when trying to load `dplyr`. Below is the code.

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
        knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, cache=TRUE)
        install.packages("dplyr", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", dependencies = TRUE)
        library(dplyr)
        weather_data <- read.csv("repdata_data_StormData.csv.bz2", header=TRUE, sep=',')
      
weather_data$human_effect <- weather_data$FATALITIES + weather_data$INJURIES
weather_data$economic_effect <- weather_data$PROPDMG + weather_data$CROPDMG
        
weather_effect <- weather_data %>% group_by(EVTYPE) %>% summarise(human=sum(human_effect, na.rm=TRUE), economic=sum(economic_effect, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Error:

```
Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called 'dplyr'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> library

Execution halted
```

Comment: why would you want to install packages in a knitr document?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I dont install the package in Knitr, it gives error that the pipe function %>% associated with dplyr package is not found. Seems like it cant recognise dplyr package.

Comment: You just remove `install.packages("dplyr", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org", dependencies = TRUE)` line.

Comment: If I remove the package command, it gives me below error:

Error in weather_data %>% group_by(EVTYPE) %>% summarise(human = sum(human_effect,  : 
  could not find function "%>%"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval

And if I only remove the install package but keep the library(dplyr) then it gives the error that dply package does not exist.

Comment: You should install packages only once. I advise my students to never include install statements in their scripts as there are other mechanisms to do this (newest attempt I like is using `renv` package). Calls to `library` should suffice. What message do you get if you install `dplyr` package manually through the console?

Comment: I updated the complete package repository in R. That resulted in removing the errors.